# How do I prevent CI from being stuck in a loop due to bumping the build number?

Tags: xcode, git, jenkins, versioning, fastlane

I have an Xcode (iOS) project on GitHub. Whenever I push changes to GitHub, I want it to push a new version to TestFlight.

This is my current set up:

1. Jenkins polls `master` branch, when a new commit is available, it launches Fast Lane.
2. Fast lane increments the build number and uploads to TestFlight.
3. Fast lane commits the build number increase and pushes the change back to `master`.

The problem is that this new commit on `master` causes step 1 to execute again, thus it's in an infinite loop.

What's the recommended way to resolve this issue?

Comment: According to [this comment](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/7644#issuecomment-268776993), there might be a way to filter out commits by a certain user while polling in Jenkins. Will try it when I get a chance and report back.

Answer (score 1):

we use a specific commit messages when Jenkins commit changes **skip ci**.

and ceated a dedicted function.

```
def call() {
    haveSKIPCICommit = sh (script: "git show --name-status | grep '\\[skip ci\\]'", returnStatus: true)
    if(haveSKIPCICommit == 0){
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

to complete the flow our Jenkinsfile use this function to check which flow should be use.

Answer (score 0):

I had to

1. define a gitblab user and use it for pushing the changes.
2. change my jenkins job to a parameterized one and define a parameter for the username (myuser).
3. add the username in my hook

   ```
   def triggerUrl = jenkinsUrl + "/job/" + jenkinsJob + "/buildWithParameters?token=" + jenkinsToken + "&myuser=" + user.getName()
   new URL(triggerUrl).getText()
   ```